# Read a csv file with rows of key-values pairs, to be used to create a new csv file with unique keys in the header, and default values in rows

Tags: php, arrays, csv, text-parsing, csv-header

I have a dataset of in a particular format in CSV

```
key=value,key2=value,key3=value
key=value,key2=value,key4=value,key3=value
```

I want to convert it to:

```
key,key2,key3,key4
value,value,value,null
value,value,value,value
```

But there are array mismatches in output csv.

I need to sort the header columns, ensure that subsequent row values are in the right columns, and if a given column value is missing use the string `null`.

This is my coding attempt:

```
if (($handle = fopen("sheet4.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $cols = explode(",", $data[0]);
        $num = count($cols);
        for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            $colData = explode("=", $cols[$c]);
            $outputHeaders[$row][$colData[0]] = $colData[0];
            $output[$row][$colData[0]] = $colData[1];
        }
        $csvOutput[$row] = array_combine($outputHeaders[$row], $output[$row]);
        $row++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

foreach ($csvOutput as $row => $rowData) {
    $extractHeaders[] = array_keys($rowData);
}

$mergedHeaders = array_unique(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $extractHeaders));

$fp = fopen('sheet4out.csv', 'wa');
fputcsv($fp, $mergedHeaders);
foreach ($csvOutput as $key => $fields) {
    $rowKeys = array_keys($fields);
    if (count($mergedHeaders) == count($rowKeys)) {
    } else {
        $differntKeys = array_diff($mergedHeaders, $rowKeys);
        $fields = array_merge($fields, array_fill_keys($differntKeys, 'banana'));
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
```

Comment: Does the file have labels like `Row1: ` in it? You're not removing that in your code.

Comment: No its just to show

Comment: Your code seems to be much more complicated than needed. You don't need an array of headers for each row, you just need one array that contains all the header names. Each row is just an associative array made from its fields.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `explode(',', $data[0])`. `fgetcsv()` already exploded the line, so `$data[0]` is just the first field.

While you're reading the input CSV, just add each field name to the headers array. You can keep this small by calling `array_unique()` after each row.

When creating the output row, you can use the null coalescing operator to provide `null` as a default value for missing keys in a row.

```
$headers = [];
$rows = [];
if ($handle = fopen("sheet4.csv", "r")) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $row = [];
        foreach ($data as $field) {
            [$key, $value] = explode('=', $field);
            $row[$key] = $value;
        }
        $headers = array_unique(array_merge($headers, array_keys($row)));
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

array_sort($headers);

if ($fp = fopen('sheet4out.csv', 'w')) {
    fputcsv($fp, $headers);
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $outrow = array_map(fn($field) => $row[$field] ?? 'null', $headers)
        fputcsv($fp, $outrow);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Open the data source file in "read" mode.
- Parse each line and build an indexed array of associative arrays from the delimited key-value pairs AND build a flat associative array of encountered keys -- this will ensure uniqueness.
- Close the source file because it is no longer needed.
- Open a new file in "writing" mode.  `w` will overwrite the whole file if it already exists; `a` will append new data to the end if the file already exists. It doesn't make sense to use `wa`, use `w`.
- Sort the headers (in whatever fashion you desire)
- Declare an associative array of null values to both order the columnar data of each row as they are iterated, and ensure that all columns have a value.
- Populate the new values while iterating, then close the file.

Code: ([Simplified Demo](https://3v4l.org/ks42p))

```
$header = [];
$rows = [];
$fileHandle = fopen("sheet4.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($fileHandle)) !== false) {
    foreach ($line as $pair) {
        [$key, $rows[$i][$key]] = explode('=', $line, 2);
        $header[$key] = $key;
    }
}
fclose($fileHandle);

sort($header);
$defaults = array_fill_keys($header, 'null');

$fileHandle = fopen('sheet4out.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fileHandle, $header);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    fputcsv($fileHandle, array_replace($defaults, $row));
}
fclose($fileHandle);
```